# iOS 14: How to open a URL in Safari app instead of user configured default browser?

Tags: ios, uikit

On iOS 14, when you open a URL via `UIApplication.shared.open(…)`, the default browser configured in Settings is opened, and the default browser app can be some app other than Safari.

Is there a way to open URL in Safari app when the default browser is configured to another app (e.g. Google Chrome)?

Comment: Seems like there is no way to achieve this at the moment.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659910